# Footnote does not show up

Tags: footnotes

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{tocbibind} % fa apparire la bibliography
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\newcommand{\ammonia}{\ce{NH3}}
\newcommand{\co}{\ce{CO2}}
\newcommand{\water}{\ce{H2O}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=3 cm, left=3.5 cm, right=3.0cm, bottom=3.0cm}
\linespread{1.5}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xr}


\begin{equation}\label{eq:Ammonia} 
\centerline{\ce{2NH3_{(g)} + \co_{(g)} <=> NH2COONH4_{(l)}}
\footnote{$\Delta H =\SI{-117}{\frac{Kj}{mol}}$ at 110 atm and 160\celsius}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:urea}
\centerline{\ce{NH2COONH4_{(l)} <=> CO(NH2)2_{(l)} + H2O_{(l)}}
\footnote{($\Delta H =\SI{+15.5}{\frac{Kj}{mol}}$ at 160-180\celsius}} 
\end{equation}
```

I want to display the footnotes at the bottom of the page, but it does not show up.

Comment: Don't use footnotes in equations. And don't use `centerline`.

Comment: and please when posting examples make them _complete_ (`\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`_ and _minimal_ (delete all packages not needed for the example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several weaknesses in your code. For instance the usage of `\centerline` that is the cause of your headache and does no purpose at all.

You're loading packages and not using them properly. And also packages that duplicate action of others you load. For instance, `gensymb` does nothing `siunitx` can do better. Also `csquotes` does much better than `dirtytalk`.

Your preamble is confused and there are many duplications. I removed some of the useless packages (if you load `float` for the `[H]` option, don't). Instead of `colortbl` and `color`, call `xcolor` with the `table` option. Also `tocbibind` should receive the `nottoc` option or the table of contents will be listed in the table of contents.

I also removed `\linespread{1.5}`; if you need increased interline, use `setspace`.

Note that `\SI{-117}{\kilo\joule\per\mol}` avoids the errors of denoting the “kilo” prefix with an uppercase letter and “joule” with a lowercase one. I set `per-mode=fraction`, but the result, as you see, is poor.

Instead of `mathptmx`, it's much better to do

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

(but I didn't change this).

Finally, instead of footnotes to displayed formulas, I'd simply add the note as text following the display. But you (or your advisor) are the final judge.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % pull away spurious warnings
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xr}

% generic set up
\geometry{a4paper, top=3 cm, left=3.5 cm, right=3.0cm, bottom=3.0cm}

\graphicspath{{images/}}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}

% personal commands

\newcommand{\ammonia}{\ce{NH3}}
\newcommand{\co}{\ce{CO2}}
\newcommand{\water}{\ce{H2O}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Ammonia} 
\ce{2NH3_{(g)} + \co_{(g)} <=> NH2COONH4_{(l)}}
\footnote{$\Delta H =\SI{-117}{\kilo\joule\per\mol}$ at \SI{110}{atm} 
  and \SI{160}{\celsius}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:urea}
\ce{NH2COONH4_{(l)} <=> CO(NH2)2_{(l)} + H2O_{(l)}}
\footnote{($\Delta H =\SI{+15.5}{\kilo\joule\per\mol}$ at
   \SIrange{160}{180}{\celsius}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Note: I cheated with the text height in order to produce a smaller picture, but this has no influence on the final result.)